HTML as parameter in Angular
I'm new to angular and would want to know if what implementation should I make to pass a parameter as HTML. In NextJS we do something like below.
NextJS:
htmlBody: JSX.Element
{{ htmlBody }}
I would want to know how can I make the implementation on Angular 15 > version.


export interface SampleInterface {
  htmlBody: [should pass html element],
  label: string,
  id: string
}



GetValueSampleInterface(val: SampleInterface) {
return (<>
{{ val.HtmlBody }}
  </>)




This question is similar to: Angular HTML binding. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It would be good to clarify what you are trying to achieve for those who are not familiar with NextJS.

I want to know if it is possible to pass html body as parameter. If so, what is the right data type for it?

I guess the question is, why do you want to do it? It's pretty unusual to do something like that in Angular

I want to pass it for a customize component.

If I understand your question correctly, you could use HTMLElement or HTMLBodyElement for your type.
